# Reporte detallado y general con parámetros para Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Quiero crear la consulta para crear un reporte detalle donde como parámetro llamado *producto* ingrese la primera letra del producto, el nombre del parámetro en el detalle es (*producto*) y me salga la lista de productos con ese nombre (por ejemplo: ingreso como parámetro "Leche" me tiene que mostrar: Leche deslactosada, Leche condensada, Leche sabor chocolate) y su fecha de vencimiento, luego quiero crear la consulta para un reporte general donde me muestre todos los productos como subreporte del reporte detalle (por ejemplo: 1. Leche: Leche deslactosada, Leche condensada, Leche sabor chocolate; 2. Yogurt: Yogurt griego, Yogurt light, Yogurt sabor fresa 3. Gaseosa: gaseosa KR, Gaseosa inca, Gaseosa coca).

Ya tengo la consulta del detalle, tengo problemas con el del general:

Esto es mi consulta del detalle:

```sql
SELECT concat_ws(' ',pr.nomproducto,m.nommarca,un.unidades),
    pp.f_vencimiento,
    p.nomproveedor,
    pp.cantidad,
    pp.idproducto,
    DATEDIFF(pp.f_vencimiento, CURDATE()) AS dias,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(pp.f_vencimiento, CURDATE()) <= 0 THEN 'CADUCADO' ELSE 'NO CADUCADO' END AS estado
FROM productoproveedor pp
INNER JOIN proveedor p ON p.idproveedor = pp.idproveedor
INNER JOIN producto pr ON pr.idproducto = pp.idproducto
INNER JOIN unidades un ON un.idunidades = pr.idunidades
INNER JOIN marca m ON pr.idmarca = m.idmarca
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(pr.nomproducto, ' ', 1) = $P{producto};    `
```

Para el general estaba tratando con esto:

```sql
SELECT nomproducto
FROM producto
WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX(nomproducto, ' ', 1) and nomproducto LIKE CONCAT('%', $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}, '%'));   `
```

pero dice que la página está vacía.

Comment: Suena a que usas el parámetro equivocado, deberías tener algo como `and nomproducto LIKE CONCAT('%', $P{producto}, '%')`.

Comment: Sii, intente colocar el parámetro en si pero no lo lee, me sale Error: General problem:Parameter "producto" does not exist.Check username and passvvord; is the DBMS active ?!